# How to solve No such table error in Android Sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I have tried to add data to the following helper class but I got a 'no such table' error.

If we use normal SQL query, it starts working. But this type of query isn't working. How to write these type queries, please explain that syntax!

```
static class EmpHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
        private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "empdatabase";
        private static final String TABLE_NAME = "emptable";
        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
        private static final String UID = "_id";
        private static final String NAME = "Name";
        private static final String PASSWORD = "Password";

        private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE" + TABLE_NAME
                + "("+UID+ " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + NAME
                + " VARCHAR(255)," + PASSWORD + "VARCHAR2(255)"+")";

        private static final String DROP_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS"
                + TABLE_NAME;
        private Context context;


        public EmpHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            this.context = context;
            Message.message(context, "constructor called");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try {
                db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);

            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple syntax problems with your `CREATE TABLE` SQL and you catch exceptions in `onCreate()`. Therefore `SQLiteOpenHelper` thinks database creation was successful even if the SQL wasn't executed.

To fix:

- Add space between `"TABLE"` and `TABLE_NAME`.
- Add space between `PASSWORD` and `"VARCHAR"`.
- Remove the `catch`. Exceptions need to be thrown to caller.
- Uninstall your app so that the old, empty database is removed and `onCreate()` is run again.

(For that matter, there's also missing space in your `DROP_TABLE`.)

Answer (score 2):

You should change this

```
 + " VARCHAR(255)," + PASSWORD + "VARCHAR2(255)"+")";
```

to

```
 + " VARCHAR(255)," + PASSWORD + " VARCHAR2(255)"+")"; //add space after VARCHAR2(255)
```

After changing this you must uninstall your app and install again new apk built